# How to specify where Samsung S5830's camera saves photos to

Tags: camera, storage

I have a Samsung S5830 phone which has Android on it.

When I look at:

- Task Manager -> Summary

It appears that my, small, sim card is being filled up with data whilst, my larger, External SD card is relatively empty.

I'd prefer the camera to save images to my SD card. Not the sim.

But, I have no idea how to tell it to do so.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Photos captured by camera were not stored on sim card, BTW. Probably they gets stored on SD-card(is available).

Comment: Thanks for your comment. If I remember corectly, I was given the impression that it was being stored on my sim because my camera stopped working saying "Full" whilst having loads of space on my SD card. I solved the problem by transfering the images onto my pc which made the cam start working again.

Comment: What options do you have when you hit the "menu" button while in the camera app?

Comment: The menu button (the soft key to the left of the lower button) does nothing. Offers no options. There are various settings softkeys surrounding the view. But these are to do with how the picture is taken (flash on|off|auto, etc) and not how it is saved.

Answer (score 1):

Your device, [Samsung Galaxy Ace S5830](http://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_i9100_galaxy_s_ii-3621.php), should be running Android 2.3. If so, you can set the storage location while within the camera app:

1. Access the camera app;
2. On your screen should be what looks like a cog wheel, tap on it;

   > for your device, while in landscape, **should be** at the left/bottom of your screen.

   [image: Android Camera app]
3. On the next screen, there's a scrollable list, make your way to part where you can set your storage location, tap on the prefered location to select.

The camera app should now store the photos taken into the selected location (Memory card or internal storage).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My phone is a Samsung Galaxy Ace S5830, but it is not running Android 2.3. It runs Android 2.2.1. Which may be why there is no `storage location` setting in my camera's settings.

Do you know if it is possible to upgrade handsets to higher versions?

Comment: @JW. There are some [recent firmwares available](http://www.sammobile.com/firmware/?page=8&view=4803) for your phone that you can install using KIES.

Comment: @JW. If you are running Android 2.2.x Froyo, by default the camera stores images to your external SD Card, at least according to the information from the [manual](http://www.neoi-technology.com/manuals/AndroidUsersGuide2.2.pdf).